# Automatically choose an assumption from local context

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I have a proof script with a section that looks like this:

```
  - destruct (IHx1 _ _ H3). subst. destruct (IHx2 _ _ H7). congruence.
  - destruct (IHx1 _ _ H6). congruence.
  - destruct (IHx1 _ _ H3). subst. destruct (IHx2 _ _ H7). congruence.
  - destruct (IHx1 _ _ H6). congruence.
  - destruct (IHx  _ _ H2). congruence.
  - destruct (IHx  _ _ H5). congruence.
  - destruct (IHx  _ _ H2). congruence.
  - destruct (IHx  _ _ H8). congruence.
  - destruct (IHx  _ _ H8). congruence.
  - destruct (IHx  _ _ H8). congruence.
  - destruct (IHx  _ _ H8). congruence.
  - destruct (IHx  _ _ H7). congruence.
  - destruct (IHx  _ _ H4). congruence.
  - destruct (IHx1 _ _ H8). congruence.
  - destruct (IHx1 _ _ H5). subst. destruct (IHx2 _ _ H9).
```

It seems like it would be a choice candidate for using `;` to solve cleanly, unfortunately the hypotheses are all over the place. How can I collapse the various sub-proofs together?

Comment: Please avoid putting full solutions to exercises in SF on the internet!

Comment: Didn't you see the only thing in red in the [introduction](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/sf/current/Preface.html#lab12)?

Comment: I apologize! I'll edit out my solution as soon as it has an answer. I would remove it now but I don't have another equally good demonstration of the problem I'm trying to demonstrate.

Comment: I think you should at least edit the names to make it hard to google this solution.

Comment: I've removed the information that identified the question. Sorry for having lacked discretion :o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cases where we have only one induction hypothesis can be solved using the following piece of Ltac (see the manual, [chapter 9](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/Reference-Manual011.html)):

```
match goal with
  IH : forall st2 s2, ?c / ?st \\ s2 / st2 -> _,
  H : ?c / ?st \\ _ / _
  |- _ => now destruct (IH  _ _ H)
end
```

Where variables prefixed with question marks, e.g. `?c`, `?st`, etc. are pattern-matching metavariables, commas separate hypotheses and the turnstile symbol (`|-`) separates the hypotheses from the goal. Here we are looking for an induction hypothesis `IH` and a compatible hypothesis `H` so we could apply `IH` to `H`. The `?c / ?st` part ensures `IH` and `H` are compatible.

The subgoals with two induction hypotheses can be solved analogously:

```
match goal with
  IH1 : forall st2 s2, ?c1 / ?st \\ s2 / st2 -> _,
  IH2 : forall st2 s2, ?c2 / _ \\ s2 / st2 -> _,
  H1 : ?c1 / ?st \\ _ / ?st'',
  H2 : ?c2 / ?st'' \\ _ / st2
  |- _ => now destruct (IH1  _ _ H1); subst; destruct (IH2 _ _ H2)
end
```

Of course, if you want you can bind names to those custom tactics, use tactical with them and so on:

```
Ltac solve1 :=
  try match goal with
        IH : forall st2 s2, ?c / ?st || s2 / st2 -> _,
        H : ?c / ?st || _ / _
        |- _ => now destruct (IH  _ _ H)
      end.
```